# unittest for python function calling os.popen

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest, popen, python-mock

I am trying to write unit test for function calling system process `os.popen`.

Function:

```
def change_from(lineTag):
    Lines = []
    command = "ls -al"
    lines = os.popen(command).readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if lineTag in line:
            temp = line.split(":")
            Lines.append(temp[1])
    return Lines
```

Initialy I just wrote a simple test:

```
def test_change_from(self):
    lineTag = "undocumented_line:"
    Lines = ['43', '45', '47', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55']
    self.assertEqual(change_from(lineTag), Lines)
```

It passed, but gave me warning:

```
 ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 encoding='UTF-8'>
  lines = os.popen(command).readlines()
```

So I tried using Mock library to "simulate" os process:

Test:

```
import unittest
import os
from mock import *

@patch('os.popen')
    def test_change_from(self, mock_subproc_popen):
        mock_subproc_popen.return_value = Mock(communicate=('ouput', 'error'), returncode=0)
        lineTag = "undocumented_line:"
        Lines = ['43', '45', '47', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55']
        self.assertEqual(change_from(lineTag), Lines)
```

And I am getting error while running test:

```
    for line in lines:
TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable
```

How could I correctly mock the os.popen process to have test passing without warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`main.py`:

```py
import os


def change_from(lineTag):
    Lines = []
    command = "ls -al"
    lines = os.popen(command).readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if lineTag in line:
            temp = line.split(":")
            Lines.append(temp[1])
    return Lines
```

`test_main.py`:

```py
import unittest
from main import change_from, os
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_change_from(self):
        with patch.object(os, 'popen') as mock_popen:
            Lines = ['43', '45', '47', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55']
            mock_popen().readlines.return_value = Lines
            lineTag = "undocumented_line:"
            self.assertEqual(change_from(lineTag), [])
            mock_popen.assert_called_with('ls -al')
            mock_popen().readlines.assert_called_once()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/58165140/main.py           10      2    80%   10-11
src/stackoverflow/58165140/test_main.py      12      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                        22      2    91%
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58165140